# How do I implement a Gchat like popup?

Tags: javascript, browser

I had Gmail open in a browser that was minimized and when someone sent me a message via gchat, i got a popup notification in the corner of the screen. The popup had no top bar (the one with the minimize, full screen, and close in the top right corner) and the close was integrated into the window in its own design. Is there a way to create a window (i.e. popup) without a top bar (in addition to without the browser bars)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [Web Notifications API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/).

Note, however, that the API is not (yet) standard and is currently only supported by Chrome.  (Although there are Firefox [extensions](https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+html5+notification) that can be installed to enable the functionality.)

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively simple, all you have to do is create an element with javascript.

Here is some sample code:

```
function makeBox() {
   box=document.createElement("div");
   div.innerHTML="HTML to go in the popup window.";
   div.id="popup";
   document.body.appendChild(box);
}
```

of course, you put an a tag like this:

```
<a href="javascript:document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('popup'));">X</a>
```

in the HTML of the popup to add the close feature. This is a simple example, you can add CSS styling and other features easily.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, which is how to show a notification *outside of the browser window*.  He's really looking for the [Notification API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8685491/201952).

Comment: Yes, but A. this wouldnt popup in a new window and B. even if it did, it would still have the top bar that I described.